# Async issues on Nativescript plugin, forced to use .get

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, nativescript

I have a JSONobject inside a java class which gets called from my Nativescript plugin.

it gets sent a url to be downloaded and saved on phone (save class not shown) then returns an object that contains height and width which gets returned back to plugin.

I would like to show progress dialog but this is not possible when using Async and the .get, I can't see any other way to download the image and return JSONObject to awaiting plugin from the onPostExecute()

```
public JSONObject downloadImage(Context context, String url) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
   Save.ReturnObj returnObj;
   DownloadImage downloadImage =  new DownloadImage();
    downloadImage.execute(imageandUrl);
    Bitmap bitmap = downloadImage.get(); // would like to do this without .get

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    returnObj = savefile.SaveImage(); //saves image and returns image heights

     //get dimesnions

    obj.put("h", returnObj.h);
    obj.put("w", returnObj.w);


    return obj; //returns this object to plugin
}
```

And here is the ansync function. Everyone says to put all the code in the onPostExecute() part, but how does this work, I need the public JSONObject downloadImage to return object based on dimesions, I can't do that from here.

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private int imagenumber;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Strng... imageUrl) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //It is redundant here, I would like this to do what happens in the public JSONObject downloadImage JSON
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `nativescript-downloadmanager` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-downloadmanager  plugin, which could help you to download your file. the plugin will show progress bar while downloading the image.